# R conditional mutate date column using groupby and fill

Tags: r, group-by, conditional-statements, fill, dplyr

similarly worded questions out there but none show quite what I'm looking to do. I have a sample of a dataframe below. I would like to group_by ID and create a Date2 column where rank=2. I'm having a hard time figuring this out.

```
     ID   Rank    Date       Date2
1   5678   1    2000-01-01   2010-05-02    
2   5678   2    2010-05-02   2010-05-02  
3   1234   1    2000-01-01   2015-06-03     
4   1234   2    2015-06-03   2015-06-03
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>%fill(Date2,.direction='up')
```

How can I go about this?

Comment: `fill` is used for a different purpose i.e. for filling the `NA` elements with previous non-NA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Date2=Date[Rank==2])
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID  Rank Date       Date2     
  <int> <int> <chr>      <chr>     
1  5678     1 2000-01-01 2010-05-02
2  5678     2 2010-05-02 2010-05-02
3  1234     1 2000-01-01 2015-06-03
4  1234     2 2015-06-03 2015-06-03
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(ID = c(5678L, 5678L, 1234L, 1234L), Rank = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), Date = c("2000-01-01", "2010-05-02", "2000-01-01", 
"2015-06-03")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "data.frame")
```

Also if you want to use `fill()` you can try this code. You would have to use a conditional like `ifelse()` to assign the date and then fill the values:

```
#Code 2
df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Date2=ifelse(Rank==2,Date,NA)) %>%
  fill(Date2,.direction = 'up')
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID  Rank Date       Date2     
  <int> <int> <chr>      <chr>     
1  5678     1 2000-01-01 2010-05-02
2  5678     2 2010-05-02 2010-05-02
3  1234     1 2000-01-01 2015-06-03
4  1234     2 2015-06-03 2015-06-03
```

Comment: @paranormaldist I also added a code with `fill()` if you feel interested in using that option.

Answer (score 0):

We can group by 'ID', get  the corresponding 'Date1' with a logical expression

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(Date2 = Date[Rank == 2][1])
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
#     ID  Rank Date       Date2     
#  <int> <int> <chr>      <chr>     
#1  5678     1 2000-01-01 2010-05-02
#2  5678     2 2010-05-02 2010-05-02
#3  1234     1 2000-01-01 2015-06-03
#4  1234     2 2015-06-03 2015-06-03
```

---

Or another option is to use `match`

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Date2 = Date[match(2, Rank)])
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Date2 := Date[match(2, Rank)], ID]
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
df$Date2 <- with(df, rep(Date[Rank == 2], table(ID)))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(5678L, 5678L, 1234L, 1234L), Rank = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), Date = c("2000-01-01", "2010-05-02", "2000-01-01", 
"2015-06-03")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "data.frame")
```